# iOS IAP testing, login doesn't say sandbox, and invalid login error

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to test In App Purchases for my iOS app. I'm pretty sure it is working with the sandbox server because I haven't published any versions of the app and my call to list products is working (`SKProductsRequest`).  I followed the docs and made sure I was logged out from App Store under system settings on my device.

Everything works fine until I get to the login prompt.  I select the option to use an existing account, then enter my login info, and I get an error saying `"The Apple ID you entered couldn't be found or your password was incorrect. Please try again."`

I'm entering the same login that I use for iTunes connect to access my developer account.  I'm the only person on the account, so it is an admin account which means it should have test/sandbox access from what I understand.

I'm running from `XCode`, the latest version of `XCode`, and testing with my iPod 5G running iOS 7.

I must be missing something simple.

Comment: create test user on itunesconnect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create sandbox users in the

**iTunes Connect > User and Roles > Sandbox Testers**

Use these accounts to login instead of your Apple developer account.

Comment: Figured it was something simple.  I had read this but pretty sure I saw my admin email address under the testers list, but I think that was a different testers list, maybe for TestFlight.  Thanks!